# How can I use Astro.cookies in my Preact component?

Tags: preact, astrojs

I want to be able to use Astro.cookies in my Preact component, it was working before in dev testing but in production, it doesn't work

I tried to do `import {AstroCookies} from "astro"` and that seemed to work but it didn't after a while

Code I attempted to use to set the cookie:

```
const data = response.json()

const sessionId = data.sessionId
const maxAge = data.maxAge

try {
    Astro.cookies.set('sessionId', sessionId, {
        httpOnly: true,
        maxAge: maxAge
    })
} catch (e) {
   console.error(e)
}
```

Comment: you'll need to post more info on what code you tried and how it failed. but basically you'll need to call `Astro.cookies` in a `.astro` file and pass it into your Preact component as a prop...

Comment: Will do and how would I accomplish doing so? I have never done it before so I am intrigued to figure out if it would work.

Comment: please post a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example of what you've tried